# getSharedPrefernces return null only in one activity which works fine on another

Tags: java, android, android-sharedpreferences

I'm using following code to save the shared preference.

```
sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
editor.clear();
editor.putString("NIC",nic);
editor.putString("fName",fName);
editor.putString("mName",mName);
editor.putString("lName",lName);
editor.putString("aNo",aNo);
editor.putString("lane",aLane);
editor.putString("city",aCity);
editor.putString("contactNo",contactNo);
editor.putString("regDate",regDate);
editor.putString("cardNo",cardNo);
editor.putString("balance",balance);
editor.commit();
```

Using following code to get the shared preference in Profile activity and it's working fine.

```
private void getPrefs() {
        SharedPreferences userDetails = Profile.this.getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        id = userDetails.getString("NIC", "");
        f_Name = userDetails.getString("fName", "");
        m_Name = userDetails.getString("mName", "");
        l_Name = userDetails.getString("lName", "");
        contact_no = userDetails.getString("contactNo", "");
        a_No = userDetails.getString("aNo", "");
        a_Lane = userDetails.getString("lane", "");
        a_City = userDetails.getString("city", "");
        card_No = userDetails.getString("cardNo", "");
        reg_Date = userDetails.getString("regDate", "");
    }
```

But when I use the same in another activity, it returns null for the id.

```
private void getPrefs() {
        SharedPreferences userDetails = Travel.this.getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        id = userDetails.getString("NIC", "");
}
```

mainfest.xml

```
<activity
            android:name=".Profile"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.pavsaranga.scat.PROFILE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Travel"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.pavsaranga.scat.TRAVEL" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

can anyone please help me to solve this issue?
the full code of the Travel Activity

```
public class Travel extends AppCompatActivity {

    TableLayout tl;
    StringBuilder sb;
    String id, result;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.travel);
        tl = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tlTravel);
        getPrefs();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                getResponse();
            }
        });
        t1.start();
    }

    private void getPrefs() {
        SharedPreferences userDetails = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        id = userDetails.getString("NIC", "");
    }}
```

Comment: It shouldn't return null. You've set the fallback string to an empty string. Maybe you actually saved the string `"null"`?

Comment: no using the Profile activity I can view the setted shared preference

Comment: Like I said, though, there is no reason the string is null. Show the full Activity code, please

Comment: please check the question, I added it there

Comment: I copied this from another activity and paste it in this activity. now it's working. I don't know what was the issue. I checked a diff of this one and previous one as well. two lines are identical. SharedPreferences userDetails = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        id = userDetails.getString("NIC", "");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this or  Profile.this to `getApplicationContext()`

Like :

```
     SharedPreferences userDetails = getApplicationContext()
.getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Comment: still it returns null only for the Travel activity. For the Profile activity it's working fine and I can view the set shared preference as well.

Comment: i added the full code of the activity on the question

Comment: Maybe you have created the Prefs with the .Profile context?
All prefs should be read and written in the same context (as @Ahmad suggested).
You should change your code in the .Profile activity too to write the preferences in the Application context and not in .Profile.this

Comment: Uninstall your app and install. Try again.And change all pref to `getApplicationContext()
.getSharedPreferences`

Comment: "All prefs should be read and written in the same context" yes I double checked that one.
"Uninstall your app and install." done
" change all pref to getApplicationContext() " done
not working still

Comment: I copied this from another activity and paste it in this activity. now it's working. I don't know what was the issue. I checked a diff of this one and previous one as well. two lines are identical. SharedPreferences userDetails = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); id = userDetails.getString("NIC", ""); thanks for your support